# BetweenPosition and WithinPosition in Biopython

Tags: python, biopython

What is the difference between "BetweenPosition" and "WithinPosition" in Biopython.

It seems like one of them is inclusive of the endpoints, and the other is not -- but the description in the Biopython documentation didn't seem to describe that explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BetweenPosition is basically obsolete and can be ignored.